# jupyter lab becomes very lagging after machine learning with a lot of data when using JupyterDash

Tags: plotly-dash

I am using JupyterDash and use Jupyter Lab to edit and run the file. When opening it the first time, it is running well, however after doing machine learning with a lot of data, jupyter lab becomes very lagging. Even I closed the browser and closed anaconda prompt and re-logged into jupyter lab, it still is lagging a lot.

so I think it is related to memory in the browser?

I don't use dcc.Store() since my data is more than 10MB. I just pass the data in callback to the function.

Here is what I used.  Thanks for your help.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(mode='external',debug=True,port=8050)
```

Comment: Please add a full example and reproducible work. What kind of data do you have?

Comment: sorry I cannot provide a full example and the data which is owned by my company. can you provide some ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try with another browser.

Comment: I just used microsoft Edge for 1 hour and it is also very lagging.  any other solutions? Thanks

Comment: Did you move to another browser? how was it at the beginning?

Comment: Thanks Hamzah, I did move to another browser and it was slightly lagging at the beginning and lagging become worse slowly.  I did try VSCode and it was not lagging at all. so something is related to jupyter lab with dash. Thanks